# WebAPI methods is not calling in Kentico

Tags: c#, kentico

I am working on WebAPI with Kentico. I implemented GET methods `TestA()`, `TestB(join,product)` and `TestC(category,code)`. I created custom module class in AppCode and defined routes but I am getting TestC method is not found.

I tried the following routes:

1st solution:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("LPNSWAPI", "LPNSWAPI/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

2nd Solution: I applied for all methods specifically but TestC method is not calling.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("LPNSWAPI", "LPNSWAPI/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("LPNSWAPI", "LPNSWAPI/{controller}/{action}/{join}/{product}", new { join= RouteParameter.Optional,product=RouteParameter.Optional });

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("LPNSWAPI", "LPNSWAPI/{controller}/{action}/{category}/{code}", new { category= RouteParameter.Optional,code=RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I also specified controller and action name for all 3 then sometimes TestB is calling then TestC is not working and If TestC is calling then TestB is not working.

Could you please suggest a solution so that I can call all three methods?

Comment: It would be great to always provide at least what Kentico version are you using. Have you followed the documentation? https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/using-asp-net-web-api-with-kentico

Comment: I am using Kentico 10 version. Yes, I followed and applied same but getting problem with parameterized method.

Comment: What type are the parameters of your TestB and TestC method? If they are same type (i.e. string & string) then the controller doesn't know which one to choose and fails.